# WiFi/Bluetooth on Android. Connection history for known networks/devices.

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-bluetooth

There is a task:

> 1. Get the names of all known wifi networks/paired devices. (actually done, was pretty easy)
> 2. Get the name of a network/device with the latest connection.

So, can I somehow get the connection **time&date of each known network/device**?

Comment: This is a GitHub repo to an open source Android WiFi Analyzer. Can any of its code help you? https://github.com/VREMSoftwareDevelopment/WiFiAnalyzer